# R: combination of each character between column

Tags: r

```
SNPA <- c('AA','AA','AT')
SNPB <- c('CC','GG','CG')
SNPC <- c('AG','AA','GG')
dat <- data.frame(SNPA,SNPB,SNPC)
result_1 <- data.frame(col1=c(rep('A',20),rep('T',4)),                       
col2=c(rep('C',8),rep('G',8),rep('C',2),rep('G',2),rep('C',2),rep('G',2)),
                       col3=c(c('A','G','A','G','A','G','A','G'),rep('A',8),rep('G',8)))
```

I have such a data of dat. I want to change dat into result_1 which each character of each element in dat was combined with each character of element in another column.For example, the first row has 8 combinations:ACA ACG ACA ACG ACA ACG ACA ACG.The third row has 8 combinations:ACG ACG AGG AGG TCG TCG TGG TGG.All these combinations form data result_1.What is the code to obtain it？

Answer (score 0):

One attempt - `strsplit` each string, then loop over each combination of the now-split-rows and apply the `expand.grid` function to get all the combinations:

```
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(expand.grid, lapply(dat, strsplit, split=""))))
#   SNPA SNPB SNPC
#1     A    C    A
#2     A    C    A
#3     A    C    A
#4     A    C    A
#5     A    C    G
#6     A    C    G
#7     A    C    G
#8     A    C    G
#9     A    G    A
#10    A    G    A
#11    A    G    A
#12    A    G    A
#13    A    G    A
#14    A    G    A
#15    A    G    A
#16    A    G    A
#17    A    C    G
#18    T    C    G
#19    A    G    G
#20    T    G    G
#21    A    C    G
#22    T    C    G
#23    A    G    G
#24    T    G    G
```

In long-form, it might be a little easier to understand:

```
spl <- lapply(dat, strsplit, split="")
spleg <- Map(expand.grid, spl[[1]], spl[[2]], spl[[3]])
do.call(rbind, spleg)
```